# How do I load 3dtiles using Vue+cesium?

Tags: vue.js, cesiumjs

Based on the information I can find, I created the vue project and referenced Cesium, where Cesium says that cesium is not defined in the vue component.

Among them, I cited Cesium in Vue's public/index.html.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejbt6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btd0J.png)

Then I tried to solve the problem using window.cesium, and although there was no error, 3dtiles would not load.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8pFs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pU9I.png)

So I tried removing the index .html reference and referencing it in main.js, but I couldn't start the server.

Newcomers have just started to work and write programs, there are many things they don't understand and English is not very good, I hope the big guys will be more inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you must install vue-cesium npm

Comment: Please provide textual information, especially code, as text, not as picture of text.

Comment: Please post your code as [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) **NOT** as [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Images%20require%20more%20bandwidth%20than,byte%20and%20every%20millisecond%20count.)